# C# Regular Expression find the string after a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a connection string

```
"User ID=abc;Password=pwd;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=PRDREPTQ)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PRRQ)))"
```

I want to use regular expression to parse out the host "PRDREPTQ" value only. Can anybody help me write the pattern?

Comment: This tool helped me a lot check it out https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution:

`\(HOST=(.*?)\)`

For example:

[image]

So in C#:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(inputString,@"\(HOST=(.*?)\)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string host_value = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Regex `HOST=(\w+)`

And capture the first group

```
string testString = "User ID=abc;Password=pwd;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=PRDREPTQ)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PRRQ)))";
var match= Regex.Match(testString, @"HOST=(\w+)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```